# Unity 2D: Destroy all overlapping objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, overlapping

I am making a 2D isometric citybuilding game. The world is devided into tiles and you can click a button to start the placement of a building. The building will follow your mouse across the map and when you click another button it will place (this works fine). But if you want to place a (new) building over another (old) building, that (old) building needs to be destroyed.

All buildings have a Ridgidbody2D (kinedynamic) and a Boxcollider2D.

[Picture: The setup for the Building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLJGa.png)

Ps: this is my first question on this forum if I could improve my questions please tell me.

```
private bool Place;
public bool Destr;
Vector2 pz;
private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

public void Awake()
{
    Place = true;
}

public void Update()
{
    if (Place)
    {
        pz = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.x) % 2 != 0)
            pz.x = Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.x) + 1;

        if (Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.x) % 4 == 0)
        {
            pz.x = Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.x);
            if (Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.y) % 2 == 0)
            {
                pz.y = Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.y) + 1;
            }
            else
                pz.y = Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.y);
        }
        else
        {
            pz.x = Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.x);
            if (Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.y) % 2 == 0)
            {
                pz.y = Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.y);
            }
            else
                pz.y = Mathf.RoundToInt(pz.y) + 1;
        }

        transform.position = pz;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Place2") && Place)
    {
        Place = false;
        float IsoX = Mathf.Abs(pz.x) / 2;
        float IsoY = (pz.y - 1 - IsoX) / 2;
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteRenderer.sortingOrder = -(20 * Mathf.RoundToInt(IsoY) + Mathf.RoundToInt(IsoX)) + 1;

        // New code

        for (var i = 0; i < Obj.Count; i++)
        {
            Destroy(Obj[i]);
        }
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(Place)
    {
        Obj.Add(other.gameObject);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (Place)
    {
        Obj.Remove(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gilles, what is your actual problem exactly? What is not working? The destruction of the old building (I assume that you correctly place the newly one but the old one remains, am I right)?

Comment: You can "remember" last collision while dragging a new building. And destroy an object that your new building touched last.

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー The old building does not destruct.

Comment: @obywan I tried your advice but it still doesn't work. I placed the new code in my post. Maybe I made a mistake in my Building settings in Unity (see picture). Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: _Maybe_ is that kinematic that gives the problem: you ignore the programmable events, this way. Despite this, have you tried by putting a log into your OnCollisionEnter (and OnCollisionExit as well, after the edit), and see if it will be printed under different settings?

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー Thank you for the advice, I solved the problem by using OnTrigger instead of OnCollision. Ps: It works in kinedynamic and dynamic.